# Can I set up mutual authentication between Salesforce and API Gateway?

Tags: aws-api-gateway

I want to set up API Gateway to point to a Lambda function which will process outbound messages from Salesforce.

All Saleforce instances share an IP range, so the way to verify that a message is from our instance is to use a cert from Salesforce to provide mutual authentication.

I know that you can use mutual authentication between API Gateway and your backend service, but I'm not sure about between the client and API Gateway. Is this possible to set up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

API Gateway does not currently support client certificate validation (aka mutual authentication) between the client and API Gateway. We have a feature request for this on our backlog, but we can't commit to a timeline for delivering it.

Comment: The horse's mouth is the best mouth